# Text on Homepage is a different color on iOS Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, colors, safari

On my top bar of my homepage, I have included the company phone number with a text color of white. It reders white on my desktop browser ( Firefox and Chrome ), renders white on my Droid phone, but redners dark gray on my iOS phone in Safari. Why does that happen on Safari? Why is Safari showing a different color for the phone number text different than what shows on my desktop browser, and Droid phone? Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
   <ul class="some-info font-montserrat">
      <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +1 888-555-5555</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
 .top-bar .some-info li {
  display:inline-block;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:48px;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size:12px;
  margin-left:50px;
  text-align:right;
 }


.top-bar .some-info li i {
 margin-right:5px;
 color:#596269;
 font-size:16px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that iOS converts it to be a link. This is for the purpose of clicking on and being able to directly call the number. My fix for this is to add a link to it and style the link to white.

Alternatively add the css below

```
.top-bar .some-info li a {color:white!important;}
```

Comment: yes that did it! Excellent feedback. Inserting your css snippet did the trick. Follow up question: "When I pull up the page on my Android phone, the phone number is also clickable, just like it is if I pull it up using my iPhone. So why does Android not change the text color as well?"

Comment: It depends on the browser being used. On android if you using google chrome, it does not link it. But if you use the default browser it does. Android uses a different method to link the tel number